# Sopa de Letras en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, .net-core

Tengo una matriz de n*n, y palabras que buscar dentro de esa matriz.

El problema es que no encuentro como poder resolverlo. Necesito que me busque las palabras horizontales y verticales.

```
for (int i = 0; i < soup.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < soup.GetLength(1); j++)
                if (word.ToCharArray()[0] == soup[i][j])
                    return true;
```

Tengo ese codigo por ahora, donde word es la palabra que mando y soup es la matriz ya cargada.

Comment: Por qué no amplías la pregunta con la declaración de las variables que intervienen no se sabe si son tipo char o tipo string. La porción de código aportada que es de una función busca palabra?

Comment: word es de tipo string recibe la palabra, eso lo aclare arriba, por ejemplo "ARBOL".
soup es una matriz n*n cada posicion es un char.

Y necesito encontrar ARBOL dentro de esa matriz recorriendola

Comment: Existen funciones que buscan subcadenas, ¿es obligado buscar carácter a carácter? o se puede hacer uso de funciones como string.Contains

Comment: No especifica nada de como o con que hacerlo, simplemente debo buscar la palabra que se pasa dentro de la matriz y encontrarla en horizontal o vertical.

No conozco algunas cosas de c# estoy aprendiendo.

Answer (score 0):

la forma de enfocarlo como yo lo veo sería hacer dos arrays auxiliares de la forma:

```
string[] strSoupHor;
string[] strSoupVer;
```

El array *strSoupHor* va a contener las cadenas de la sopa de letras en horizontal y el array *strSoupVer* pues contendrá las cadenas de la sopa de lertras que se forman en vertical.

Lo siguiente es crear un método para rellenar dichos arrays:

```
void GetStringsSoup(char[,] p_Soup)
{
    int x = p_Soup.GetLength(0);
    int y = p_Soup.GetLength(1);

    strSoupVer = new string[y];
    strSoupHor = new string[x];
    // Conformamos las cadenas horizontales
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            strSoupHor[i] += p_Soup[i,j].ToString();
    // Conformamos las cadenas verticales con tan sólo
    // invertir el orden de los for
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            strSoupVer[j] += p_Soup[i,j].ToString();

}
```

Bien, ahora lo que precisamos es de una función que busque la cadena. Ya eso es fácil haciendo uso del método Contains del tipo *string*. Y la vamos a crear de forma que devuelva el índice de la cadena si lo encuentra o bien -1 si falla (esto servirá más adelante para obtener la posición):

```
int SearchWord(string p_Word, string[] p_SoupStrings)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p_Soup.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        if (p_SoupStrings[i].Contains(p_Word))
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Bien, ya está todo. Ahora vemos cómo lo usamos, primero nuestra sopa de letras:

```
char[,] soup = new char[6,5] { {'A', 'X', 'C', 'B', 'C'},
                               {'A', 'A', 'C', 'J', 'C'},
                               {'3', 'R', 'X', 'B', 'C'},
                               {'3', 'B', 'P', 'K', 'C'},
                               {'3', 'O', 'W', 'C', 'A'},
                               {'4', 'L', 'L', 'U', 'Z'}
                             };
// La palabra que vamos a buscar
string palabra = "ARBOL";

// Conformamos los strings vertical y horizontal
GetStringsSoup(soup);

// Así buscamos ARBOL horizontal y verticalmente donde devuelve distinto de -1 si
// la búsqueda tuvo éxito.
int posHor = SearchWord(palabra, strSoupHor);
int posVer = SearchWord(palabra, strSoupVer);
```

Si ya quisiéramos saber la posición de la palabra, basta con hacer uso del método *IndexOf* ya implementado en el tipo *string* de la siguiente forma.

```
if (posVer != -1) // Si se encontró verticalmente, busco su posición
{
    int pos = strSoupVer[posVer].IndexOf(palabra);
    //
    // La palabra comienza en soup[pos, posVer]
    // 
}
if (posHor != -1) // Si se encontró horizontalmente, busco su posición
{
    int pos = strSoupHor[posHor].IndexOf(palabra);
    //
    // La palabra comienza en soup[posHor, pos]
    // 
}
```

Comment: Consulta
Tu for no tendria que ser doble for?
`int SearchWord(string p_Word, string[] p_SoupStrings)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p_Soup.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < p_Soup.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (p_SoupStrings[i][j].Contains(p_Word))
                return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}`

Comment: No, ahí voy recorriendo un array de cadenas, por eso se hace con un simple for. Y con cada cadena comparo si contiene la subcadena que es la palabra que tratamos de buscar. Y si la encuentra retorna el índice de la cadena dentro del array de dichas cadenas donde hemos encontrado la palabra. La función es simple y la usamos para buscar tanto las cadenas horizontales como verticales, lo que cambia es el array que le pasamos como parámetro.

Comment: Si entiendo, es lo mismo 
char[][] alfabeto = {
new char[] {'a','b','c','v'},
new char[] {'l','k','d','v'}
}
Porque lo tengo armado asi a la sopa

Comment: Lo único que en lugar de acceder soup[row,col] como yo lo he planteado tendrás que adaptarlo y acceder así soup[row][col]. No obstante es más fácil simplemente cambiar la sopa de letras y no tendrás que tocar nada en el código.

Comment: Si intente hacerlo, pero me dice que Contains no existe para char, entiendo que es para string, pero porque podria reemplazarlo ahi

Comment: A ver, el código te marca las pautas a seguir y el enfoque del problema; lo primero es poder crear las cadenas como explico en la respuesta. Teniendo el array de cadenas la búsqueda es sencilla con el método Contains. Tu array char[][] sólo es el mapa del juego y de él extraigo las cadenas no opero con él salvo para extraer las cadenas. Si te quieres manejar con el propio mapa entonces has de buscar tu palabra carácter a carácter lo que implica más código.